# My code is not functioning as expected with the try and except function within python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

So I'm having a strange issue with Python which is related to the try and except function. It is supposed to allow me to reinput the customer which in this case is c2 as c1 is transferring funds to c2. However it gives me a keyerror instead of saying that the user is not in the database and asking me to reinput the customer name. The second use of try and except in the below code works though although there is a visual bug and not functional bug.

I've tried changing where I use try and except and have tried searching online but have not found a solution. I've only been doing Python for a few months and it is on and off at that.

```
elif option == 3:
            print("Option", 3)
            try:
                    c2 = input("Customer 2")
                    customer2 = BankSystem.c[c2]
            except ValueError:
                print("\n>>>An exception occured ~ invalid i/p")
                print("\t~Customer not in database")
            print()
            if "c2" in BankSystem.c: ## check for valid account id
                print(customer2)
            try:
                    amount = float(input("Amount to transfer "))
                    self.tranfer(customer2, amount)
            except ValueError:
                print("\n>>>An exception occured ~ invalid i/p")
                print("\t~Non-numeric data entered")
            else:
                print("\n>>>>>>>account:{} does not 
exist".format("c2"))
            print(self)
            print(customer2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, "Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary." So, you should check for keyerror in your except block:

```
try:
    c2 = ....
except KeyError:
    print("\n>>>An exception occured ~ invalid i/p")
    print("\t~Customer not in database")
```

**Edit:**
You can restructure your try/except as:

```
        try:
            c2 = input("Customer 2")
            customer2 = BankSystem.c[c2]
            if "c2" in BankSystem.c: ## check for valid account id
                print(customer2)
                amount = float(input("Amount to transfer "))
                self.tranfer(customer2, amount)
            else:
                print("\n>>>>>>>account:{} does not exist".format("c2"))
            print(self)
            print(customer2)
        except KeyError:
            print("\n>>>An exception occured ~ invalid i/p")
            print("\t~Customer not in database")
        except ValueError:
            print("\n>>>An exception occured ~ invalid i/p")
            print("\t~Non-numeric data entered")
```

Comment: If I type KeyError instead of value error and enter something incorrect other than c2 such as c3 then it gives me the error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'customer2' referenced before assignment

Comment: Another thing, I think it should be: for c2 in Banksystem.c instead of for "c2" in Banksystem.c in your code?

Comment: customer2 is being used after except block which should not happen. So,it is better to wrap your entire segment that uses customer2 in one try except block.

Comment: I appreciate the tips guys, unfortunately I'm very new to all of this and especially with try and except. I spent a month of uni basically just learning about print statements lol. Would you mind explaining in a little more detail if possible so I can understand better. Thank you.

Comment: In try except, if exception(error) is met, the except block is executed. Then all the lines below the except block also gets executed. I think this is causing problems in your program as customer is being used below the except block. So, you should put all the code that is run after a customer in a single try-except block I hope this helps. I will try to edit my answer.

Comment: Hmm, if no except block was triggered, it should work as before. Once compare with your working code. The restructuring should work fine.

Comment: Hi, just deleted my comments as I'm an idiot sometimes haha. Managed to miss a line somehow. Everything working completely fine now as I had missed the self.transfer line so it wasn't transferring. Thanks so much man, you really helped save me with this, hopefully I can look over the differences and better understand why your method works so well. I've still got much to learn.

Comment: Yeah it happens. I am also just a student, these things will get easier with more experience. There may be an even better way to implement this, so keep trying and learning different things. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
it gives me a keyerror
```

This is caused by fact that in this line

```
customer2 = BankSystem.c[c2]
```

you are trying to access `dict` with key `c2` (given by user). If there is not such key `KeyError` happen. Note that instead of using `try-except` you might check if `dict` has key following way:

```
d = {'a':1}
k = input('key:')
if k in d.keys():
    print('key present')
else:
    print('key not present')
```

Will print `key present` if you give it `a` and `key not present` in all other cases.

Comment: That's just causing lots of issues for me such as undefined names. I'll link my whole code below as that may be of more use:https://pastebin.com/3Rqdf4NU

Comment: My snippet is only example, it is not supposed to fit into your code, you should write own code fitting your case.